# Is there an alternative to google blocked searches?

Tags: google, reconnaissance

I'm trying to do some research on google. I'm using specific keywords like inurl, site, etc....  But google seems to think I'm trying to do harm (actually I'm doing recon on a website for a friend)... So it displays this message

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot

What can I do against it ? Is there an alternative to google to recon using a web crawler without being blocked ?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a security question.

Comment: There are other search engines out there. And if you are targeting a single site, there are tools that connect directly to the site and analyse it...

Answer (score 1):

If continuing with regular search queries, you need to change your IP address, as simple as this. Users using proxies in the cloud often experience such issue, just because even though they have their unique IP addresses, somebody on the same subnet is doing a large volume of Google queries. I'm not sure if this was the case for you, but if you used a cloud provider to proxy your queries, this happens very often.

The wording of your question implies that you automate your queries with a program. Or you are the one that makes too many requests. In this case you'd be better to request a token from Google and use their APIs instead, where you can't get blocked. [This is the API page.](https://cse.google.com/cse) You can make up to 10K queries per day.

Comment: Nope I'm not using any computer program. For instance running many times dorks from exploit-db will trigger the error.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for some time for google to unblock you and try to run the recon using FOCA. FOCA uses a single search query to download all non HTML files which reduces the number of attempts. You can also run the dorks from TOR (of course you will have to enter the CAPTCHA a couple of times).

Comment: Nope I'm not using any computer program. For instance running many times dorks from exploit-db will trigger the error.

Comment: I am suggesting you to use dorks clubbed together rather than running them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is the search content of your requests triggering this message.  Are you, perhaps, using Tor, in which case you searches are coming from the same IP address as others using the same Tor exit node.  If so, run your searches from your own IP address and not through Tor, to help scan your friend's website.

Comment: Nope I'm not using any computer program. For instance running many times dorks from exploit-db will trigger the error.